# C#: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array"

Tags: c#

I would like to start by saying that I am not a developer and this is my very first time writing a code to this extend of complication (at least to me). Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

The idea of this program is to retrieve the employee user ID (or signature) from an API URL once the name has been entered.

1. I created a class that identifies the information that needs to be retrieved from the API (Below is the code):

   ```
    namespace TimeSheet_Try11_Models
    {
        public class Employeename
        {
            public List<string> Signature { get; set; }
            public List<string> FirstName { get; set; }
            public List<string> FullName { get; set; }
            public List<string> LastName { get; set; }
        }

    }
   ```
2. Next I created a folder called WebAPI which will access the API and retrieve the needed information. (please see the code)

   ```
    namespace TimeSheets_Try_11.Controllers
    {
        class WebAPI
        {
            public string Getsignature(string name)
            {


                var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora), false);
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
                wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                string uri = "";

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                uri = StaticStrings.UrlIora + name;
                var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);


                string json = @"[{'signature':'JANDO','firstName':'Jane','fullName':'Deo, Jane','lastName':'Deo'}]";

                Employeename status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeename>(json);

                string signature = status.Signature.ToString();
                return signature;


            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Finally, the following code is my code for the forms that will retrieve and display information.

   ```
        namespace TimeSheets_Try_11
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                WebAPI WA = new WebAPI();
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora);
                }

                private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string strurltest = string.Format("https://iora.UniversityofHouston.com/api/dictionary/employee/" + textBox1.Text);
                    System.Net.WebRequest requestObjGet = WebRequest.Create(strurltest);
                    requestObjGet.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    requestObjGet.Method = "Get";
                    HttpWebResponse reponsObjGet = null;
                    reponsObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();



                    string[] usernames = new string[] { "Koehne, Craig", "Bergeron, Ronald" };
                    string[] userid = new string[] { "CKOEH", "RONBE" };

                    for (int i = 0; i < usernames.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (textBox1.Text.Contains(usernames[i]))
                        {
                            textBox2.Text = userid[i];
                        }

                    }

                    string sgname; string projectstring;
                    projectstring = textBox1.Text.ToString();

                    sgname = WA.Getsignature(projectstring);

                }

                private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                    string StringConn = textBox1.Text;


                }

                private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
   ```

Problem: The code does not seem to have any errors, however when I start debugging the code, it gives me an error that states:

> "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
> current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'TimeSheet_Try11_Models.Employeename' because the type requires a JSON
> object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

Comment: `@"[{'signature':'JANDO','firstName':'Jane','fullName':'Deo, Jane','lastName':'Deo'}]";` is a json array, try `var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(json);`

Comment: Also please read about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON string contains an array that contains one object. But you're trying to deserialize it into just a single object.

Either deserialize the JSON string into a C# array:

```
string json = @"[{'signature':'JANDO','firstName':'Jane','fullName':'Deo, Jane','lastName':'Deo'}]";

Employeename[] status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeename[]>(json);
```

Or change the JSON string so it's no longer an array, just an object:

```
string json = @"{'signature':'JANDO','firstName':'Jane','fullName':'Deo, Jane','lastName':'Deo'}";

Employeename status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeename>(json);
```

Also, your `Employeename` class makes no sense, the properties should be of type `string`:

```
public class Employeename
{
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I tried the first option of removing the square brackets and it gave me the error of:
'Error converting value to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path 'signature', line 1, position 21.'
I also tried the second way of Employeename[] status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeename[]>(json); however I now have a line under the string signature = status.Signature.ToString(). Explaining that Employeename[] does not contain a definition for 'Signature'

Comment: @programmer101 I glossed over it at first, but I just noticed your `Employeename` class makes no sense. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I did try it with this format as well. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error in the same spot.

Comment: The error essentially says that it cannot convert whatever is in your JSON to a `List<string>`. If you're still getting that error, you still have a `List<string>` somewhere that you're not supposed to have a List. With the class in my answer and the JSON in my answer, everything works.